# How do I work out which shapefile (suburb) contains a given lat-lon point in PHP

Tags: php, shapefile

I only have access to PHP5 (no PostGIS)

I have a bunch of suburb shapefiles, and a few events with lat-lon points. I've zero experience with shapefiles.

What is the best way to check which shapefiles contain these lat-long points (using only PHP)?

Do I convert the shapefiles to a lat-long polygon and use standard polygon-point intersection equation?

Or is these some awesome PHP library for loading/working with Shapefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each shapefile consists of 3 parts, shp,shx,dbf.  The shp file contains the geometry, shx is an index to help access the shp, the dbf is plain old dbase file that contains data for each record.

You can extract the bounding box from the shp file as follows,

```
$handle = fopen("path/to/file.shp","rb");
fseek($handle, 36);
$min_x = unpack("d",fread($handle,8);
$min_y = unpack("d",fread($handle,8);
$max_x = unpack("d",fread($handle,8);
$max_y = unpack("d",fread($handle,8);
// Note, this code will only work on a little-endian machine
// You'll need to do a byte swap on big endian systems
```

Then you can test to see if a given event lies in the shapefile's bounding box.

```
if (($event_x >= $min_x) && ($event_x <= $max_x) 
      && ($event_y >= $min_y) && ($event_y <= $max_y))
```

You can put this is a loop and get a subset of your shapefile that overlap with a given event.  This doesn't mean you event is inside a polygon in a given shapefile, but it'll get you close.  If you need an exact solution you'll have to extract the polygons and do a point in polygon test.

Disclaimer: Consider the above code pseudo code, I don't know php, so there are probably some bugs. Also, If you can switch to python things get a lot easier, there are existing libraries that provide shapefile parsing and spatial indexing, so you can determine exactly which polygons a point intersects with in a highly efficient manner.

Ref: ESRI Shapefile Whitepaper, http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To work with shapefiles, I suggest loading them into a database with spatial relations, and using the spatial relation capabilities of the database.

I personally use PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension for this. It has a utility for converting the shapefiles into an SQL insert. Then you can put your point into WKT (well known text) and query the database for what shapefile(s) it intersects with.

I do not believe php itself has any built in functions for dealing with GIS.

**EDIT-** Damn - I'm sorry, I didn't see the (no PostGIS) part until after the post. You might be able to convert your polygons to wkt and use a polygon-point intersection.

Comment: The asker has no access to PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but as a service to the community and future users looking for similar functionality in native PHP, I'd like to point out that my [PHP Shapefile](https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile) is a free and open source PHP library that can read and write any ESRI Shapefile, without any third party dependency.

Link to GitHub project: https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile